# New Indications via OpenFDA API

Tags: api, openfda

Is it possible to access new indication submissions or approvals via the OpenFDA API?

I can see the information that I am looking for via the the Drugs@FDA website. For example, the [page for Jakafi](https://www.accessdata.fda.gov/scripts/cder/daf/index.cfm?event=overview.process&ApplNo=202192) has submissions labeled as "Efficacy-New Indication".

[image: New indication data available via website]

However, when I try to [query the same information via the the Drugs@FDA API](https://api.fda.gov/drug/drugsfda.json?search=openfda.brand_name:%22JAKAFI%22), the same submissions are returned without the "New Indication" label.

API Query:
`https://api.fda.gov/drug/drugsfda.json?search=openfda.brand_name:%22JAKAFI%22`

API Response Excerpt:

```
{
          "submission_type": "SUPPL",
          "submission_number": "23",
          "submission_status": "AP",
          "submission_status_date": "20210922",
          "review_priority": "PRIORITY",
          "submission_class_code": "EFFICACY",
          "submission_class_code_description": "Efficacy",
          "submission_property_type": [
            {
              "code": "Orphan"
            }
```

Comment: You can actually just scrape this content

Answer (score 3):

openFDA builds its *Drugs@FDA* dataset from the downloadable [data files](https://www.fda.gov/drugs/drug-approvals-and-databases/drugsfda-data-files) at the FDA. Unfortunately, the information you are looking for is currently absent from these files: if you scroll down to the ER diagram on that page you will see a note saying

> ActionTypes_Lookup (a linking table will be provided in the near future)

The "linking table" hasn't been provided yet, which is why we are unable to extract the information to openFDA. Sorry about the inconvenience.

Comment: I could not find the text "a linking table will be provided in the near future". Has this been implemented now? Is the Information the OP asked now available on OpenFDA?