# Submissions data not showing for all drugs in Drugs@FDA

Tags: data-request, drugs

I'm using the Drugs@FDA API to get data on submissions (e.g. for when labeling changes) for a list of drugs. I've noticed that sometimes I can get a "Submissions" table beneath "Results", but not always.

For example, I can see the submissions for HUMIRA
https://api.fda.gov/drug/drugsfda.json?search=products.brand_name:%22HUMIRA%22

But cannot see submissions for ALINIA
https://api.fda.gov/drug/drugsfda.json?search=products.brand_name:%22ALINIA%22

Checking against a direct search of Drugs@FDA, it's not as if ALINIA doesn't have any supplemental materials connected to its NDA. What explains why I don't consistently see the Submissions table? Is this the same problem as described here? [New Indications via OpenFDA API](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/20014/new-indications-via-openfda-api)